# Is possible to edit the Windows 7 login screen (code)?

Tags: windows, login-screen

I'm developing a program that opens immediately when the user do the login. But I also wanna do a different login, like that if the user press Ctrl + Enter otherwise Enter, the program don't open.
Is possible do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...the answer to the title is No, unless you work for Microsoft and are willing to get your boss mad at you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're talking about would be to implement a Credential Provider DLL. This would provide a replacement for the standard login screen (the one where you enter username and password). Credential Provider DLLs are primarily intended to support alternate types of credentials, like smart cards or fingerprint scanners, but there's no reason you couldn't use one in the manner you describe.

With one exception: "the program don't open" is not going to happen. When a new logon session is created, an instance of winlogon is launched in the new session; winlogon.exe launches loginout.exe , and then loginout loads the credential provider DLL; all this happens before your code can make any decisions. But, you could refuse to handle the login if the user enters the wrong keystrokes.

You cannot, practically, speaking, replace either winlogin or loginout.

n.b.: Security by obscurity (e.g. a "secret handshake" keystroke sequence) is worth approximately zero.